# GLSL type inconsistencies

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm currently using the following fragment shader for basic black and white effects:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float time_passed_fraction;

//gl_Color: in the fragment shader, the interpolated color passed from the vertex shader

void main()
{
    // lookup the pixel in the texture
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    vec3 texel = pixel .rgb;

    gl_FragColor = pixel;
    float bw_val = max(texel.r,max(texel.g,texel.b));

    gl_FragColor.r = pixel.r * (1-time_passed_fraction) + bw_val * time_passed_fraction;
    gl_FragColor.g = pixel.g * (1-time_passed_fraction) + bw_val * time_passed_fraction;
    gl_FragColor.b = pixel.b * (1-time_passed_fraction) + bw_val * time_passed_fraction;
    gl_FragColor.a = pixel.a;

    // multiply it by the color
    //gl_FragColor = gl_Color * pixel;
}
```

This fragment shader works perfectly on my PC. But I'm getting some feedback from people that they're getting the following errors:

```
ERROR: 0:17: '-' :  wrong operand types  no operation '-' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'const int' and a right operand of type 'uniform float' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
ERROR: 0:17: '*' :  wrong operand types  no operation '*' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'float' and a right operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
ERROR: 0:18: '-' :  wrong operand types  no operation '-' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'const int' and a right operand of type 'uniform float' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
ERROR: 0:18: '*' :  wrong operand types  no operation '*' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'float' and a right operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
ERROR: 0:19: '-' :  wrong operand types  no operation '-' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'const int' and a right operand of type 'uniform float' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

This seems to allude to some type errors, but I'm not understanding where the inconsistencies are coming from. Could someone perhaps explain?

Note: line 17 is this line) `gl_FragColor.r = pixel.r * (1-time_passed_fraction) + bw_val * time_passed_fraction;`

Comment: IIRC old versions of GLSL didn't do implicit int-to-float conversions; you may have to use `float(myinteger)` to convert them explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing `#version` directive at the beginning of your shader implies `#version 110` which as Colonel Thirty Two noted does not support implicit `int` -> `float` conversion.

Note that `typeof(1)` == `int` != `float` == `typeof(1.0)`.

So your lines like this:

```
gl_FragColor.r = pixel.r * (1-time_passed_fraction) + bw_val * time_passed_fraction;
                            ^ nope
```

Need to be:

```
gl_FragColor.r = pixel.r * (1.0-time_passed_fraction) + bw_val * time_passed_fraction;
                            ^^^ fix'd
```

Comment: Thanks - do you also happen to know if 1.0f also works, or does GLSL only support 1.0?

Comment: @dk123: Nope, no `f` suffix in [`#version 110`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.10.59.pdf).